# Function returning weird output when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a function that compares two dataframes (data and ref) in order to find similar rows between them.

The function works like that:

```
def get_ref(row, reference):

    match = np.isclose(row, reference.values, atol=5, equal_nan=True).all(axis=1)

    return reference[match].index[0] if match.any() else "unidentified"
```

and I use it like that:

```
match = pd.DataFrame({'name': _data.index, 'reference': np.apply_along_axis(get_ref, axis=1, arr=_data.values, reference=_ref)}, dtype=str)
```

And the output is :

```
    name                                    reference
0   7e592b3b-74c1-4fe2-b2c8-2cd1cb814b86    unidentified
1   90471d88-3116-42b0-82bf-b4071a669ba9    Y74C9A.3
2   89cc6b73-743c-479a-a72b-f9163f47283b    Y74C9A.3
3   7eaee653-35da-45c5-a410-425c105c3084    unidentified
4   48744bdb-ca3b-4a13-a68d-00cd87cd61a4    unidentified
5   111bc3b7-edd8-41b9-9fb1-22bf7142765a    unidentified
6   c5a392cb-b8e0-407c-9456-ecfdf59f7a4d    unidentified
7   f417ad40-9674-4fdc-a16f-89d6afa7d2ff    unidentified
8   875bada8-9fde-4b7d-822f-85bf6d0ccc3f    unidentified
9   fd47e0dc-dfcc-4bfe-9363-083718fbd28d    unidentified
10  78e4ca7b-d588-48c5-b14e-d933d7eb86ea    unidentified
11  8283c91b-03da-4d76-a3bc-971524996148    unidentified
12  3aab659d-04bb-4591-a3f7-db6259d8a394    unidentified
13  b3265905-13b0-4d3c-9e42-e901ba46348e    Y74C9A.2a.5
14  339175fc-8390-42c7-9661-f75541bd5ef0    Y74C9A.2a.5
```

Now because I needed to speed things up I've decided to use `multiprocessing`. So this is the code I came up with:

```
def get_ref_mp(data, ref):

    df = data.groupby(['X'])
    type = df.groups.keys()

    workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=workers)

    args = [(df.get_group(i), ref.loc[ref['Y'].isin(i)]) for i in type]

    result = pool.starmap(_get_ref_apply, args)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    return pd.concat(result)


def _get_ref_apply(data, ref):

    _data = data.drop(['X'], axis=1)
    _ref = ref.drop(['Y'], axis=1)

    match = pd.DataFrame({'name': _data.index,
                          'reference': np.apply_along_axis(get_ref, axis=1, arr=_data.values, reference=_ref)}, dtype=str)

    return match

def get_ref(row, reference):

    match = np.isclose(row, reference.values, atol=5, equal_nan=True).all(axis=1)

    return reference[match].index[0] if match.any() else "unidentified"
```

The problem is that now I get some weird output with some strings being truncated:

```
    name                                    reference
0   f23c7178-c02f-4f89-aef1-e291d8da2672    unidentified
0   aedaf687-a08e-4fce-bcca-1ec837d1c92b    AC3.12
1   745c50c1-a13a-4af9-b4fa-ac24f0ab8e39    uniden
0   3745591f-f1b7-4c54-8b18-8158b0fada7f    unidentified
1   7795891d-fc49-4984-b3bc-8c7a387a5091    unidentified
2   f1e3eb4d-75bc-4842-95be-2f216493ee64    unidentified
3   39ec6152-b659-49bd-84c5-b1a29b261e0a    unidentified
4   af396c92-a3c6-4641-8d22-e79194837c17    unidentified
0   016a643b-7a89-4341-b80a-1f8199a7c427    AH9.3
1   cef4ad50-0266-4f8b-aff1-03a47d3e61f4    unide
0   8991fa94-1f6e-4056-b57a-5fbc2b5c0c8e    unidentified
0   d30042f7-7e12-4232-8281-ebc51e617b69    unidentified
1   73f1c424-902d-42fc-b64b-dbe34350d334    B0001.2
```

From what I saw the truncation seems to be *process-dependent* (index 0 means it's a new process).

- First I noticed that if the first row returns `"AC3.12"` (which is 6 characters long), the next rows will only returns 6 characters max, hence I got `"uniden"` instead of `"unidentified"`. Same behavior with `"AH9.3"` etc.

I'm running python 3.6 on mac OSX 13 and the problem arise in both pycharm and jupyter notebook.

I don't really know where it comes from so I'm hoping someone around here can figure it out for me or give me some advice! Thanks a lot in advance.

**UPDATE:**

<del>- Second, when it returns `"AC3.12"` it's actually supposed to return `"AC3.12.1"`. Or `"AH9.3"` instead of `"AH9.3.1"`. And even if the first row start with a long string like `"unidentified"`, it only returns `"B0001.2"` instead of `"B0001.2.1"` so I guess everything after the second dot is truncated anyway...</del>

Comment: Have a try with: `'reference': np.apply_along_axis(get_ref, axis=1, arr=_data.values, reference=_ref).astype('object')`

Comment: Thanks for looking into it but it didn't change anything. When I use it without multiprocessing I don't have any issue, but then when I use multiprocessing the problem arise.

Comment: I think it has to do with numpy casting to a fixed length unicode dtype at some point. When you print out `match` within `_get_ref_apply` the line before you return, is the print already truncated too?
The fact that you don't encounter this without multiprocessing might be because your rows don't have to be chunked up and your first row happens to host the longest string "unidentified",  so the casting for the whole DataFrame is made to a length which doesn't truncate anything.

Comment: @Darkonaut If it helps, I realized that my second point was not an issue with the code itself but a discrepancy between the reference table saved on my computer and the reference informations posted online. It's actually returning the good value when it's the first row. Yet, the truncation still remain for next rows (as stated in my first point). I tried to run `_get_ref_apply` as pointed out and it runs ok. So I guess the problem comes from `get_ref_mp` ..